# How to use my library in my another spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I create my custom exception library to use custom exception in my another project.
But I have problem importing my library in my another spring boot project. How can I import my custom library?

I built my exception spring boot project and made JAR file, then added it to libraries in my another spring boot project structure.

[image: IntelliJ Project Structure]

But, I cannot import my library.
[image: Cannot import]

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use Gradle to add the library to your new component?
If your modules are separated and are not under a single main module, you should install your library into your local repository using the gradle command.

Comment: I also tried to use the gradle command like followings.
`implementation files('libs/exception-1.0.0.jar')`
But I also met the error... :(